# Java Selective Generics

Tags: java, generics, types, parameters

```
class A <T> {

    private T field;
}
```

I know I can force the type parameter to be of some bounded type using < ... extends ... >, but how can I force type parameter T to be ONLY either a String, Integer, SomeClassB, SomeEnumC and not be able to parametrise it with anything else?

```
A<SomeClassB> a = new A<SomeClassB>();
```

Would be legal.

```
A<SomeClassX> a = new A<SomeClassX>();
```

Would be illegal.

I have already tried to test for these types using

```
T instanceof SomeEnumC
```

in the constructor for class A, but it is very messy.

Comment: You cannot do exactly what you're asking. Why would you want to anyways? The only methods those classes have in common are the methods from `Object`.

Comment: `T instanceof SomeEnumC` should not work.  Generic type information exists at compile time only, and so there is no type information for `T` that can be used by the instanceof operator at run time.

Answer (score 2):

***Note:** I agree with @Jeffrey's comment above, that this doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, since it doesn't seem like you could gain any useful type information by doing this kind of restriction. I'd really be curious to know what your use case is here.*

---

You can't restrict the generic types acceptable for `T` to a list of unrelated classes like in your example. You can only restrict generic types using `super` or `extends`, meaning they have to be super- or sub-types of some given type.

However, since you seem to have a limited number of classes you want to allow for `T`, you should just be able to enumerate all of them. Here's what I'm thinking:

```
public class A<T> {

  /**
   * Private constructor means only nested classes
   * can extend this class. We use this to limit the
   * types that can be used for T.
   */
  private A() { }

  /** Integer version of A */
  public static class IntA extends A<Integer> { }

  /** String version of A */
  public static class StringA extends A<String> { }

}
```

Now you can use a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) to import whichever nested version of `A<T>` that you want, or all of them like this: `import static A.*;`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to export Class A as part of your API and this is why you want to restrict the types that can be passed as generic type parameters.

If the list of types that you want to restrict Class A to is known (and reasonably small in number) then a workaround is to define a package-private interface instead (this will prevent classes that are outside your package from implementing the interface):

```
interface A <T> {
    T field;
}
```

You can then simply write concrete classes for the types you wish to allow.  Because nobody else can implement your interface, there is no possibility of someone writing a class based on a type that you did not intend to permit.

Comment: I am writing a code generator for ARM assembly code. Class A is actually an instruction like MOV with few operands, which I want to restrict to types mentioned above for extra type safety.

Comment: Ah, op codes.  How about representing your op codes as an enum?  You could define an instance field or fields for each op code that specified that types that were allowed for that code.  You can't get compile-time type checking with a solution like this, but at least it turns the problem of restricting to particular types to an exercise of specifying meta-data in your Enum class.  In other words, rather than writing a class for each op code ... specify each op code as an enum constant with constant-associated metadata in a Rich Enum Type.

Comment: I caught my own mistake in the above code snippet.  Interfaces may not declare instance fields unless they are `static` and `final`.  The interface definition given above would likely not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restrict it at compile time, but with a slight tweak you can enforce it at run time:

```
class A <T> {
    private T field;
    public A(Class<T> c) {
        if (c != String.class | c != Integer.class | c != SomeClassB.class | c != SomeClassC.class)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is probably flawed, and that a better design would avoid needing to do this at all. However, if you really want to go this route, use a private constructor and factory methods:

```
public class A<T> {
    private T field ;

    private A(T t) {
        this.field = t ;
    }

    public static A<String> getInstance(String s) {
        return new A<String>(s);
    }

    public static A<Integer> getInstance(Integer i) {
        return new A<Integer>(i);
    }

    // etc....

    // regular instance methods...

    public void doStufF() {
        if (field instanceof Integer) { /* ... */ }
        else if (field instanceof String) { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

Any time you see the ugly if/else switching on type, you should be thinking "rich enum...", as in the discussion following scottb's answer.